# Detecting click outside map control using OpenLayers 2?

Tags: openlayers-2

My problem is the following:

1. User loads form containing map control and then clicks the edit icon and  starts editing a shape on the map.
2. The shape is in edit mode as you can see the handles.
3. Unfortunately when the user clicks the Save button the map updates are not captured.
4. The current work-around is to click in a blank area outside the shape. This causes the handles to disappear and the Save operation succeeds.

My question: what event should I register in the map object that would detect change of focus. That is, moving out of the map control.

If could handle this event I thought I could deactivate the map (remove the handles by turning off the edit mode) and therefore allow the map to be saved correctly.

Here's a picture illustrating my problem:

[image]